# Loop through columns and rows and copy values into new column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, transpose

I am still quite new to R and I am trying to complete the data wrangling but I am little bit stuck.

I have my data in R organized in the following data frame format (dimensions [24,17]):

```
Id  a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   k   m   n   o   p
1   999 2   2   999 999 999 999 2   2   2   2   2   2   999 999 999
2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
4   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
5   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
6   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
7   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
8   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
9   999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999
10  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
11  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
12  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
13  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
14  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
15  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
16  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
17  1   3   4   999 2   999 999 999 2   999 999 999 2   2   2   999
18  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
19  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
20  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
21  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
22  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
23  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
24  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

What I try to achieve is to have one column filled with the values for every 8th row (starting from row 1, so row 1,9,17 etc.) where the values other than 999 will be copied below each other in the single column. Where the row only consists of 999 values, I want 8 times 999 below each other in the column. In this particular example with 24 rows the column will be filled (based on row 1, 9, 17) as follows with dimensions [1,24]:

```
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
1
3
4
2
2
2
2
2
```

This means that I have to iterate through every column, starting with column 1, row 1 until the end of all columns in row 1 and than move to row 9 column 1 until the end of all columns in row 9 etc. 
I looked at examples in R transposing rows to columns with conditions, but I was not able to get the job done.

Given my lack of knowledge here, does someone knows a way to get this done in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can first extract the relevant rows using `seq`.

```
df1 <- df[seq(1, nrow(df), 8), ]
```

Then using `apply` row-wise we can check if all the values in that row is 999 and return the output accordingly.

```
c(apply(df1, 1, function(x) if(all(x == 999)) rep(999, 8) else x[x != 999][1:8]))
 #[1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999  1 3 4 2 2 2 2 2
```

If needed as one column dataframe, we can wrap `data.frame` around this output.